# Fill the area between two arcs and x-axis between two circles

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I am trying the fill the area between the two circles below their point of contact as shown below:

[image: sample 1]

What I want is something like:
[image: sample 2]

You need not worry about other details in the sample, just to fill the colored part. I tried actually using `..controls (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)..` but it is very painstaking and boring. I am looking for more efficient way to do this. I have defined their point of contact with the help of `intersection`. Here's my minimal WE:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc,angles}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
%frames
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) coordinate (origin) -- (23,0) coordinate (a1) node[right]{$x$}; % x-axis
\draw[thick,->] (origin) -- (0,20) coordinate (a2) node[above]{$y$}; % y-axis
\draw[name path=lline,thick] (origin) -- (60:22.25) coordinate (a3) node[anchor=south west]{$l$}; % l-line

%circle 1
\coordinate (CC1) at (1.7299,1){};
\coordinate[label={[red]below:$C_1$}] (C1) at (1.7299,0){};
\tkzDrawPoint[red,scale=2pt](CC1)
\tkzDrawCircle[name path=circle1,red](CC1,C1);
\draw[thick,red](C1)--(CC1) node[right,pos=.5]{1};
\draw[name intersections={of=lline and circle1}] (intersection-1) coordinate (A1);
\draw[thick,red](A1)--(CC1) node[above,pos=.5]{1};

%circle 2
\coordinate (CC2) at (5.19690701,3){};
\coordinate[label={[blue]below:$C_2$}] (C2) at (5.19690701,0){};
\tkzDrawPoint[blue,scale=2pt](CC2)
\tkzDrawCircle[name path=circle2,blue](CC2,C2);
\draw[thick,blue](C2)--(CC2) node[right,pos=.5]{3};
\draw[name intersections={of=lline and circle2}] (intersection-1) coordinate (A2);
\draw[thick,blue](A2)--(CC2) node[above,pos=.5]{3};

%% circle 1 and circle 2 point of contact
\draw[name intersections={of=circle1 and circle2}] (intersection-1) coordinate (A3);

%section color
%\fill[purple] (C1) ..controls (2.74,0.19) and (2.81,0.81)..  (A3) ..controls (5,0.10) and (3.5,0.81).. (C2) -- cycle;

%\fill[red] (5,0.10) circle (2pt) (3.5,0.81) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should never be forced to define coordinates with that many digits in a simple diagram like this. Orthogonal projection can be used many paces like `(CC1 |- 0,0)` instead of `(C1)`. You do not really take advantage of the powerful `tkz-euclide` that can do all these things. I have limited knowledge about it and can not help, but many on this site can.

Comment: As a side note, I find it disturbing not to draw everything in `tkz-euclide` if possible. Some minor things are easier to do in plain Ti*k*Z, but if you chose to use `tkz-euclide`, it seems a better option to learn more from it and try to do the most with it.

Comment: I am learning `tkz-euclide` only recently so I don't know most of the macros yet, but really it's very powerful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc,angles}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
%frames
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) coordinate (origin) -- (23,0) coordinate (a1) node[right]{$x$}; % x-axis
\draw[thick,->] (origin) -- (0,20) coordinate (a2) node[above]{$y$}; % y-axis
\draw[name path=lline,thick] (origin) -- (60:22.25) coordinate (a3) node[anchor=south west]{$l$}; % l-line

%circle 1
\coordinate (CC1) at (1.7299,1){};
\coordinate[label={[red]below:$C_1$}] (C1) at (1.7299,0){};
\tkzDrawPoint[red,scale=2pt](CC1)
\tkzDrawCircle[name path=circle1,red](CC1,C1);
\draw[thick,red](C1)--(CC1) node[right,pos=.5]{1};
\draw[name intersections={of=lline and circle1}] (intersection-1) coordinate (A1);
\draw[thick,red](A1)--(CC1) node[above,pos=.5]{1};

%circle 2
\coordinate (CC2) at (5.19690701,3){};
\coordinate[label={[blue]below:$C_2$}] (C2) at (5.19690701,0){};
\tkzDrawPoint[blue,scale=2pt](CC2)
\tkzDrawCircle[name path=circle2,blue](CC2,C2);
\draw[thick,blue](C2)--(CC2) node[right,pos=.5]{3};
\draw[name intersections={of=lline and circle2}] (intersection-1) coordinate (A2);
\draw[thick,blue](A2)--(CC2) node[above,pos=.5]{3};

%% circle 1 and circle 2 point of contact
\draw[name intersections={of=circle1 and circle2}] (intersection-1) coordinate (A3);

%fill
\begin{scope}
\clip (CC1) circle[radius=1] (CC1) -- (CC2) -- (C2) -- (C1);
\clip (CC2) circle[radius=3] (CC1) -- (CC2) -- (C2) -- (C1);
\fill[magenta] (CC1) -- (CC2) -- (C2) -- (C1);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with filled area under circles]

Like this the filled area covers half of your lines. You need to rearrange to order, so that first the coordinates are defined, and then the fill is drawn and finally all the lines.

Comment: The faint line joining the centres may be because your clipping paths are very similar to the region that is filled, so anti-aliasing effe to when the image is viewed mean that the fill bleeds through. I would use the `reverse clip` key defined somewhere on this site- I'll see if I can find the original.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12010/86

Comment: @AndrewStacey: No need to use `reverse clip` - just use a larger area e.g. `\clip (CC1) circle[radius=1] (0,0) rectangle (CC2);
\clip (CC2) circle[radius=3] (0,0) rectangle (CC2);
\fill[magenta] (CC1) -- (CC2) -- (C2) -- (C1);
`

Answer (score 6):

Here is another option that needs the `background` library. And I draw the filling twice (two options). The first one is to fill trapezium behind the circles, and the second one to fill exactly the desired area using `arc`s.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
% axes, tangent
\draw (0,6) |- (8,0);
\draw (0,0) -- (60:7);
% circles
\foreach\i/\j in {1/red,2/blue}
{
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\r{2*\i-1} % circle radius
  \pgfmathsetmacro\x{\r/tan(30)}  % circle center x
  \coordinate (T\i) at (\x,0);    % tangent point (below) 
  \coordinate (C\i) at (\x,\r);   % center
  \draw[\j,fill=white] (C\i) circle (\r);
  \fill[\j] (C\i) circle (1pt);
  \draw[\j] (60:\x) -- (C\i) node [midway, above] {$\r$} -- (T\i) 
                             node [midway, right] {$\r$} node [below] {$C_\i$}; 
}
% filling (two options, comment one of them)
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[magenta] (T1) -- (C1) -- (C2) -- (T2) -- cycle;         % fills a trapecium behind the circles
%\fill[green]   (T1) arc (-90:30:1) arc (210:270:3) -- cycle;  % fills exactly the desired area
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MarkA.Bromuela, this is the way to use `\foreach` instead of `pic`s, as I said in a comment to a related previous question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614715/how-to-match-the-blue-violet-line-with-the-orange-line-in-this-tikz-picture

Answer (score 4):

Here a version with only `tkz-euclide` (version 4 available in a short time)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
  
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \tkzDefPoints{0.5/{sqrt(3)/2}/J,1/0/I,0/0/O,{1/tand(30)}/1/A,{3/tand(30)}/3/B} 
   \tkzDefLine[bisector](I,O,J) \tkzGetPoint{K}
   \tkzDefPointsBy[projection= onto O--I](A,B){C1,C2}
   \tkzFillPolygon[magenta](C1,A,B,C2)
   \tkzDrawCircles[fill=white](A,C1 B,C2)
   \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,O,C1,C2) 
   \tkzDrawLines[add=0 and 8](O,I O,J O,K)
   \tkzDrawSegments(A,C1 B,C2)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

A better solution without `fill=white`, always with the new version of `tkz-euclide v4`. You need to use a new option `out`. This option allows you to make a clip on the complementary part of a disk(complementary to the bounding box).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \tkzDefPoints{0.5/{sqrt(3)/2}/J,1/0/I,0/0/O,{1/tand(30)}/1/A,{3/tand(30)}/3/B} 
   \tkzDefLine[bisector](I,O,J) \tkzGetPoint{K}
   \tkzDefPointsBy[projection= onto O--I](A,B){C1,C2}
   \tkzDrawCircles(A,C1 B,C2)
   \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,O,C1,C2) 
   \tkzDrawLines[add=0 and 8](O,I O,J O,K)
   \tkzDrawSegments(A,C1 B,C2)
   \tkzClipCircle[out](A,C1)\tkzClipCircle[out](B,C2)
   \tkzFillPolygon[magenta](C1,A,B,C2)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of some macros provided by `tkz-euclide` and do some more calculations on your own to draw this segment by hand, of which you essentially already know all the necessary values. Clipping, however, as proposed in the other answer, may be better, because my approach is prone to rounding errors.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc,angles}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
%frames
\draw[name path=xline,thick,->] (0,0) coordinate (origin) -- (23,0) coordinate (a1) node[right]{$x$}; % x-axis
\draw[thick,->] (origin) -- (0,20) coordinate (a2) node[above]{$y$}; % y-axis
\draw[name path=lline,thick] (origin) -- (60:22.25) coordinate (a3) node[anchor=south west]{$l$}; % l-line

%circle 1
\coordinate (CC1) at (1.7299,1){};
\coordinate[label={[red]below:$C_1$}] (C1) at (1.7299,0){};
\tkzDrawPoint[red,scale=2pt](CC1)
\tkzDrawCircle[name path=circle1,red](CC1,C1);
\draw[thick,red](C1)--(CC1) node[right,pos=.5]{1};
\draw[name intersections={of=lline and circle1}] (intersection-1) coordinate (A1);
\draw[thick,red](A1)--(CC1) node[above,pos=.5]{1};

%circle 2
\coordinate (CC2) at (5.19690701,3){};
\coordinate[label={[blue]below:$C_2$}] (C2) at (5.19690701,0){};
\tkzDrawPoint[blue,scale=2pt](CC2)
\tkzDrawCircle[name path=circle2,blue](CC2,C2);
\draw[thick,blue](C2)--(CC2) node[right,pos=.5]{3};
\draw[name intersections={of=lline and circle2}] (intersection-1) coordinate (A2);
\draw[thick,blue](A2)--(CC2) node[above,pos=.5]{3};

%% circle 1 and circle 2 point of contact
\draw[name intersections={of=circle1 and circle2}] (intersection-1) coordinate (A3);

%section color
\tkzGetPointCoord(A3){Aiii}
\tkzGetPointCoord(C2){Cii}
\tkzCalcLength[cm](C1,CC1)\tkzGetLength{rCi}  % or use `1` directly
\tkzCalcLength[cm](C2,CC2)\tkzGetLength{rCii} % or use `3` directly
\fill[purple] (C1) arc (-90:{atan(\Aiiiy/\Aiiix)}:\rCi) arc ({atan(\Aiiiy/\Aiiix)+180}:270:\rCii) -- cycle;

%\fill[red] (5,0.10) circle (2pt) (3.5,0.81) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```